# maven spring test application contexts

Tags: spring, maven, testing

I want to use the applicationContext.xml in my src/main/resources directory from within my test harness in src/test/java.  How do I load it?  I have tried:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class TestService {
...
}
```

but get a file not found error.  I'm using Maven and Spring.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (note the asterisk):

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
```

Comment: `classpath*` searches all entries on the classpath. This will directory which contains `applicationContext.xml` from `src/main/resources`. It will also search jar on classpath.

Comment: very nice, clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven test classpath uses the files in `target/test-classes`. That folder contains Java classes from `src/test/java` and resources from `src/test/resources`.

The way to go is to create a test specific app context and store it under `src/main/resources`.

You may try to reference the file directly using `file:` i.e. something like `file:src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml` but to me this is an ugly hack.

Also, you can of course use the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to copy `applicationContext.xml` prior to test execution.

Comment: I want to test with the exact applicationContext.xml that it will run with.  To me, it verifies the context file.

Comment: That's fine but you should do that with an integration test and not with a unit test.

Comment: Hmm, you have me thinking now. Unit test vs integration test.  Do you know where I can read more about these?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it, it may or may not be the best way for you. The main thing is it works in both Eclipse and Maven:

- Keep exactly one copy of each `applicationContext-xxx.xml` file per project. NEVER copy-and-paste them or their contents, it'll create a maintenance nightmare.
- Externalize all environmental settings to properties files (e.g. `database-prod.properties` and `database-test.properties`) and place them in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` respectively. Add this line to your app contexts:

  <`context:property-placeholder location="classpath:**/*.properties"/`>
- Create a superclass for all test classes and annotate it with a context configuration:

> ```
> @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
> @Ignore
> public class SpringEnabledTest {
>
>   // Inheritable logger
>   protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
>
> }
> ```

- Add `<additionalClasspathElements>` to your `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration to make sure surefire picks up appContext and the right properties files. I've created an example [here](http://pastebin.com/LPckTAxq).
- Add the location(s) of the app context files and `src/test/resources` to your Eclipse classpath so you can execute unit tests in Eclipse as well.
- NEVER add `src/main/resources` to your Eclipse classpath, it's only a convenient place for Maven to package additional source files, it should have no bearing on Eclipse. I often leave this directory blank and create additional folders (e.g. env/DEV, env/UAT and env/PROD) outside of the `src/` folder and pass a parameter to the build server and let it know from which folder it needs to copy files to `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the src folder to the classpath of your testing tool.  If it's in Eclipse, I think you can do it from the project properties.  You may have to change it to classpath:**/applicationContext.xml as well.